# Is it possible to know RSA's public key while you only know private key

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman for my mobile app's service. As last stage of my implementation i need to encrypt the publickey of ECDH with RSA . But since we only can encrypt with RSA's publicKey and decrypt with privateKey, i am thinking that i should give the privateKey to the clients and keep publicKey to service, I am little confused about whether its okay to expose the private key or not.
Is it possible to extract the publicKey from privateKey ?

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            responseVal = ResponseVal,
            responseText = ResponseText,
            ServerECDHPublicKey = serverPublicKey,
            ServerECDHPublicKey_AES = Security.EncryptAES(null, serverPublicKey, aes),
            AESKey_RSA = Security.EncryptRSA(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(aes.Key))
        });
```

Comment: The private key is supposed to be... well... private. Why do you want to give it out? What would the clients do with the private key they can't do with the public key?

Comment: “i am thinking that i should give the privateKey to the clients and keep publicKey to service” Well… no. The private key is the one you keep private. Why are you encrypting a public key?

Comment: A *private* is key called *private* because it is supposed to be kept private, by the owner of the RSA key pair. On the other hand, the *public* part is supposed to be distributed. [Bruce Schneier's Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) is a great source of information regarding security and cryptography in general, including specific applications.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question as it stands, yes, you can create a public key from just an RSA private key. The public key is just a modulus and an exponent. The private key contains the same modulus, and the exponent is predictable. Neither part of the public key is considered secret, either. Please edit your question to be about the actual problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: I need to prove the client that i am the one who send the public key of ECDH so i need to encrypt the ECDH's public key with RSA so when the client gets the response they will compare the encrypted ECDH's publickey with plain ECDH Publickey then oh okay its him :D I need to achieve this somehow and the only thing that comes to my mind was to distribute the privatekey.

Comment: You need both the public and private key to decrypt any data.  The private key is usually a permanent key that rarely changes and is installed on both the sender and receiver of a message.  The public key is available over the network by both the sender and receiver of a message.

Comment: @atakatasoy: Sounds like you’re looking for a signature, not encryption. Signatures are created with a private key and verified with a public key. It’s kind of rare in most apps to need to work with this directly, though, instead of using some preexisting protocol like TLS (“don’t roll your own crypto!”). What are you using the ECDH keys for?

Comment: @Ry- Honestly , i just started to learn cryptography. My initial goal was to create a secure communication for my app which has sensitive information. But as i am researching, things got too deep and i ended up with this. Actually i just heard signature from you. Didnt know it could be done via this way.

Comment: @jdweng are you talking about the RSA ?

Comment: @Ry- But basically what i am trying to do is , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsXMMT2CqqE

Comment: @atakatasoy: If you’re trying to secure real-world communications between your client and server, use TLS (`https://…`). If you’re trying to secure connections between clients, you might be looking for something like the [Signal Protocol](https://github.com/signalapp). If you’re just trying to learn and *not working with real sensitive data*, an app probably isn’t the simplest way to start out, and you can ask more focused questions on [Crypto.SE] and/or [Security.SE].

Comment: @Ry- Okay , Thanks!

Comment: @Ry- We would not be able to extract the public key from the private key (public key consists of public exponent and private exponent and a common modulus). While we can guess the public exponent in practice, in principle, there is no way to 'extract' (derive) it as OP wanted it. Since if one could extract the public key form the private key, the converse would be true as well. Update: The above is in the context of RSA but would hold for diffie-hellman too.

Comment: @RavindraHV: As I understand it, the OP doesn’t *want* to derive it, the OP wants to know if it’s attackable in that way (easy to misinterpret because it’s a use of encryption that doesn’t make sense), which it is. (Not sure how “since if one could extract the public key form the private key, the converse would be true as well” follows.)

Comment: @Ry- In case of RSA, we first choose a convenient (small exponent) as public value and then calculate the private exponent for that using the Chinese remainder theorem (euler's totient function). While there a few popular public key exponents (65537 being one of them), its not strictly mandatory that its always that. In mathematical terms, there is no way to derive it (although since the public exponent is typically a smaller integer its easy to arrive using bruteforce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few answers in the comments. So just posting the general idea as an answer.

> I am trying to implement Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman for my mobile
> app's service.

Ok. So the understanding is that the key derivation is at the application level. If HTTPS (TLS) is used as mentioned by [Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry), it does it for you (under-the-hood so to speak).

> As last stage of my implementation i need to encrypt the publickey of
> ECDH with RSA . But since we only can encrypt with RSA's publicKey and
> decrypt with privateKey, i am thinking that i should give the
> privateKey to the clients and keep publicKey to service, I am little
> confused about whether its okay to expose the private key or not.

Again as mentioned by [Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry) you actually need to 'sign' the ephemeral public key. That way you keep the private key to yourself (which is also mentioned in the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsXMMT2CqqE) you posted in the comments) and share the public key with the client - as per design.

> Is
> it possible to extract the publicKey from privateKey ?

Actually ***no***. While there are few common parameters, the public and private key are so called because they, as a whole, have unique parameters. For example, in case of RSA, the public key consists of a 'public' exponent and the modulus and the private-key consists of the 'private' exponent and the <s>exponent</s> modulus. As such while its possible to 'guess' the public exponent (or simply extract it from the server certificate during ssl handshake), its not possible to extract it from the private key, strictly speaking.

Update : You can also consider using JWE [(JSON-Web-Encryption)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) in conjunction with JWS [(JSON-Web-Signature)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) for the purpose. It pretty much does what you wanted to do.

Regards,

Ravindra

Comment: I re-design both mobile app and the service according to it. Now i am signing the public ECDH with private RSA. sorry if i misexplain myself :) Thanks